# EF detect migration error but database in actual state

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two projects. First project is API that call database via Entity Framework. Second project is a desktop application that uses same classes. But when i try to select data with `EF` in desktop application i got the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model backing the '<modelName>
' context has changed since the database was created. 
Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database    
(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

But API project works fine. I use codefirst database migrations.
I've cleaned solution, make sure that all migration was applied to appropriate database and entities in correct state.

i have Entity Framework 6.0.0.0

Comment: Have you tried setting the DataContext initializer to null? It seems you are migrating your database before running the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options:

1. First the error to be ignored by adding `Database.SetInitializer<API.Repository.MyDatabase.MyContext>(null);` but using your context definition to the start-up code of you desktop application.
2. Check your database to determine what the cause of your error is; the migrations use a table called `__MigrationHistory` to check the status of the database against your code. The last row should be the same as our last migration. If they are different then you need to review you migration.
3. If you don't have any data you need to retain then revert all migrations and run `Add-migration` and `Update-database`.